# About the Lindelöf degree of $(R) ^I$

Tags: general-topology

We already know that if $(R) ^ I$ is a Lindelöf space, then $I$ is countable. Is there a generalization of this proposition? If the Lindelöf degree of $(R) ^ I$ is a cardinal $\lambda$, it can be concluded that the cardinal of $I$ does not exceed $\lambda$?
My first attempt was a generalization of the proof of the numerable case, but the classical argument rests in the fact that a regular Lindelöf space is automatically normal, and $(R) ^ I$ is not normal if $I$ is not countable, so a generalization in this way is not evident.
Thank you for the further answers.

Answer (score 1):

If $l(\mathbb{R}^I) = \kappa$, then I think $|I| \ge \kappa$ is pretty clear: if we'd have $|I| = \lambda < \kappa$, then $l(\mathbb{R}^I) \le w(\mathbb{R}^I) = |I|\cdot \aleph_0 = \lambda< \kappa$, which is a contradiction.

It wouldn't surprise me if $l(\mathbb{R}^I) = |I|$, for infinite $I$.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually true. By means of the weight, we have that |$I$| cannot be less than $\lambda$. So, the problem actually is an equality between the Lindelöf degree and |$I$|.

Comment: Can we use a similar argument now for the weight in this case? If $\omega(\mathbb(R) ^I) = \lambda$, the inequality that you already give above implies the searched equality.

Comment: @user78594 what do you mean? It is classical that $w(\mathbb{R}^I)  =|I|$ for $I$ infinite, but for Lindelöf degree it's harder, I think. It could be that $l(\mathbb{R}^{\aleph_2}) = \aleph_1$ e.g. The weight ($\aleph_2$) would then be greater than the Lindelöf degree, but for non-metrisable spaces that's not unheard of. My observation only confirms $\aleph_2 = |I| \ge \aleph_1$, which is we already knew anyway.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is around the Lindelöf degree itself, and, making a simple-minded comparison between this and the open problem about  hereditarily Lindelöf- hereditarily separable spaces, I can guess that maybe this problem has no solution yet.